# Which distros build the kernel with amdgpu southern islands support enabled?

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, distribution-choice, gpu, amd-graphics

Are there any linux distributions that ship with kernels all ready built with `CONFIG_DRM_AMDGPU_SI=Y`? Mainly I would rather not attempt to compile a kernel at the moment and I have a spare partition open and would like to try out the new drivers.

I have a "southern Islands" gcn v1.0 AMD Pitcairn XT gpu, FirePro w7000. While the radeon driver is ok for watching video I really originally bought the card for its compute capability ie openCL, and because it was known performer with Auto-desk cad products(I was dual booting with windows7 at the time of purchase) and so I need amdgpu[-pro?] for compute uses.

I'd trade in the card for a better supported model but other than power consumption it seems equivalent to an RX 570 and I'm short on cash.

Comment: This isn’t an exhaustive answer, hence a comment; Debian 9 doesn’t enable this, Fedora 27 and 28 do.

Comment: No list of such dynamic things can be exhaustive. I'm on Deb9 right now(with backport kernel 4.16) I thought Fedora might but couldn't find any clear and up to date answer.

Comment: The backported 4.16 kernel for Debian 9 *should* enable it (see [the kernel configuration here](https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/linux/blob/stretch-backports/debian/config/config))...

Comment: Slipped right by me, I need some more sleep... I'm just going to search .configs of various distros tomorrow. 
I don't want to play with my Deb install anyway need it for chores and I'm getting short on backup machines. 
Oh and something something Wayland.